# Computer vision library for Ruby

Tags: ruby, computer-vision

What library do you recommend for computer vision in Ruby?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Since OpenCV is quite widely used I'd probably have a look at [Ruby/OpenCV](http://d.hatena.ne.jp/ser1zw/20101208/1291816370).

Edit: I just remembered an interesting blog post about OpenCV in Ruby from a couple of month ago, this should get you up to speed with the lib:

http://jeffkreeftmeijer.com/2011/pure-ruby-colored-blob-detection/

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Isn't there some sort of documentation for this library?

Comment: None that I know of, $SEARCHENGINE may help.

Comment: @Michael: What'd be the Ruby equivalent of that pseudo-bash?

Answer (score 2):

I am the main developer of the [HornetsEye](http://www.wedesoft.de/hornetseye-api/) library. It runs under GNU/Linux and it provides image processing operations as well as extensive integration of I/O libraries.